# How to call an attribute inside the model in FLASK SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I'm trying to call an attribute inside a model in SQLAlchemy this way

```
app = Flask(__name__)
app.config.from_object('config')
db = SQLAlchemy(app)

class Show(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'Show'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    venue_id = db.Column(
        db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('Venue.id'), nullable=True)



class Venue(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'Venue'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    upcoming_shows = Show.query.filter(Show.venue_id == 1).filter(
        Show.start_time >= func.current_date()).all()
```

I want to replace 1 here with the id of the current Venue.. I tried the following:

- self.id: returns "Undefined variable: 'self'"
- id: returns "Cannot compile Column object until its 'name' is
  assigned"

Thanks for help

Comment: Could you provide `db` and `Model` class? I can't figure the dependencies here.

Comment: Maybe you can instead use `relationship` in the `Venue` model for `upcoming_shows`. See how to use `relationship` here https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/basic_relationships.html#one-to-many

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest solution is to use a [hybrid property](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/mapped_sql_expr.html#using-a-hybrid).  A hybrid property is accessible like a normal attribute, but it can run queries to retrieve its value.

```py
from sqlalchemy.ext.hybrid import hybrid_property


class Venue(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(50))

    @hybrid_property
    def upcoming_shows(self):
        upcoming_shows = Show.query.filter(Show.venue_id == self.id).filter(
            Show.start_time >= db.func.current_date()).all()
        return upcoming_shows


@app.route("/", methods=["GET"])
def index():
    venue = Venue.query.first()
    shows = venue.upcoming_shows
    ...
```